# What does NotStrictEqual do in xUnit?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, xunit.net

What does NotStrictEqual do in xUnit in below code

```
// Act
var response = await _client.GetAsync("/api/articles");

// Assert
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var articles = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Article[]>(responseString);
Assert.NotStrictEqual(PredefinedData.Articles, articles);
```

Answer (score -1):

"Not strict equals" means you want to test negation of equality of the state of two objects irrespective of their parameter types. For ex, comparing "1" and 1 will be evaluated to true in not strict mode.

Since you have not posted the type definition for Article type I have taken some assumptions below. Also, since we're comparing custom types it's better to try `notDeepStrictEqual`. See below if it helps.

```
describe('Test articles', function () {

   const PredefinedData = {
        Articles: [
            {
                name: 'article1'
            }
        ]
   }

    it('this will pass', function () {
        const mockResponse = '[{"name": "article2"}]'
        const articles = JSON.parse(mockResponse);
        assert.notDeepStrictEqual(PredefinedData.Articles, articles);
    });

    it('this will fail', function () {
        const mockResponse = '[{"name": "article1"}]'
        const articles = JSON.parse(mockResponse);
        assert.notDeepStrictEqual(PredefinedData.Articles, articles);
    });

  });
```

Comment: in above example articles count equals 1 but PredefinedData.Articles count equals 2. It passes .Is that normal?

Comment: Sounds good. Can you test it otherwise as well? Make articles count & predefinedData.articles count equal. And then see if your test case passes.

Comment: I tested with different records (different vallues) in  `PredefinedData.Articles` and `articles`  but it passes . why?

Comment: Hi @unosbaghaii, I have update my answer. Can you try something similar in your code?

Comment: my sample code is in .net core 2 (c#). your code is javascrript. Is this test reliable?

Comment: Yeah right now I don't have .net core setup. But the behaviour should be same. Code I pasted just for your reference. You can focus only on the way I used `notDeepStrictEqual` method.

Comment: `notDeepStrictEqual ` is not available in xunit. I just wanted to know why when two object's properties are not equal, `NotStrictEqual` passes .

Comment: The question states it is .net.